# How to get a linux directory listing for files beginning with a certain letter that doesn't descend into subdirectories?

Tags: linux

Suppose you are in a directory that contains many files and many subdirectories.

You want to get a directory listing of all the files beginning with the letter "d". You type

```
ls d*
```

and what you get back is mostly files in sub-directories (in particular, files in subdirectories that begin with "d").

How do you list only the files and directory names in your current directory?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Ah, I just found it on the 6th reading of the man page. It's the not-so-sensibly named "directory" parameter

```
ls -d d*
```

Comment: It took you just 29 seconds to re-read the man page *and* write up this answer? That's quick :-)

Comment: Additionally, ls -d d*/ will only show the directories.

Comment: balpha - I discovered it before submitting the question, then realized that if it took me so long to figure this out, I might as well help a future searcher out and post the q and a here.

Comment: Fair enough; there's nothing wrong with it.

Comment: -d option will only list directories and not files.So above solution won't work

Comment: And yet, CppLearner, it does indeed work. Try it.

Comment: `man` offers forward (`/`) and backwards (`?`) regex search, case insensitive by default. The more you use it, the smarter you get at guessing right key word(s)

Answer (score 10):

I believe another interesting solution to be,

```
ls | grep ^d
```

Offers the flexibility of regular expressions.

Comment: And the complexity of regular expressions! ;-)

Comment: That is an interesting soln, and I like the idea of using regexs, however, if you add additional parameters to ls it will break. E.g. "ls -l | grep ^d"

Comment: True, but not all parameters. ls -a | grep "^\." would print all "hidden" files.

Comment: other `ls flags` do not work when using this approach. e.g. `ls -ltr | grep ^d` doesn't work. while the one suggested in @dggoldst answer does.

Answer (score 4):

find . -maxdepth 1 -name d* -type f

Okay, using find here is a tad of overkill. Just a tad.

Comment: But it helped me list all direct directories of a specific user : `find /home/ -maxdepth 1 -type d -user www-data`. So thanks, and +1

Answer (score 3):

`ls -ld`: It will give the list of directories, without descending into subdirectories.

Example:

`ls -ld Cust*`
This command will provide a listing of the files and directories which start with `Cust`.

Comment: This is essentially the same as the five-year-old accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

**ls -a | grep "^."**

ls -a: it will demonstrate all files and folders (hidden files and unhidden files together)

grep "^.": it will filter the result, and it will choose to show you just the files starts with a point.