# ? wildcard produces unexpected result in LS directory search

Tags: linux, command-line

I'm trying to get the hang of the CLI (command line interface).

At the overall root directory, I did the following:

```
root@droplet:/# ls ?tc
```

I expected to get just the `etc` directory in the result list.

However, I got a huge list of files and directory. This list was even (and much) longer than when I simply did `ls` without any additional criteria. **Why?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am presuming from your phrasing that you were expecting one result to be returned:

```
# ls ?tc
etc
```

but you actually got several results.

The question mark is a [globbing character](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/globbingref.html), as defined by:

> `?`
>
> **wild card**. The `?` character serves as a single-character "wild card" for filename expansion in globbing, as well as representing one character in an extended regular expression.

What happened is the wildcard was expanded by the shell (presumably `bash`) **before being passed to `ls`**<sup>1</sup>. So `ls` treated it as:

```
# ls etc
```

Which would have returned the many 'files and folders<sup>2</sup>' of `/etc`.

---

<sup>1</sup>: You can test that expansion happens *before* a command is executed by trying: `echo *` - this will (should!) echo back the files and directories in the current directory.

<sup>2</sup>: If you want to get to get to grips with the command line, prefer the term *'directory'* to *'folder'* :-)

Comment: Thank you so much for the clarification. I edited and changed 'folder' to 'directory'... originally a Windows user, please forgive me ;-)... I have a follow-up question. Let's say I want to list all files and directories whose names are 3 letters long, and the last two letters are 'tc'. Is there any way I could have used '?' as a wildcard to list items meeting these criteria? If not, then is there any other wildcard character that would do the job?

Comment: You're most welcome! It's a small thing, the terminology- but it helps ;-) For your supplemental question, does it have to be `bash`-only? If not, you could use grep with a period (`.`) character: `ls / | grep .tc`. (see http://www.robelle.com/smugbook/regexpr.html for examples)

Comment: Doesn't have to be `bash` only. Actually this is a good example of the difference between `bash` and `grep` to me... so that's an additional find for me here. Thanks! (And I'm guessing that this directory parameter here would do the trick with pure `bash`: http://superuser.com/questions/25910/how-to-get-a-linux-directory-listing-for-files-beginning-with-a-certain-letter-t )

Comment: Welcome to the madness of `bash` :) You are exactly right, and that parameter is new to me (though strictly it is a parameter to `ls` as opposed to`bash`); it does mean you wouldn't have to pipe/redirect (`|`) to `grep`: `ls -d /?tc` works as you describe!

Comment: PS Once you get to grips with `bash` a bit more, it's useful to know some [common pitfalls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls) and [gotchas](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/gotchas.html) once you start scripting. Good hunting!